# Need a piece of code that calcultates the exact date according to a defined position of the sun on the ecliptic

Tags: javascript, astronomy

Is there a code in javascript that can calculte accurately the date (YY-MM-DD HH:MM) when the sun arrives at a certain longitude (°) on the ecliptic ?

I've tried to use sunscalc.min.js but it seems it doesn' recognize the getDateFromAngle function.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

I tried to use the getDateFromAngle function

Comment: Thank you for your help Hermanboxcar. I have updated my message. I will test the piece of code and will give feedback. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: just use an ephemeris? [Jet Propulsion Laboratory Development Ephemeris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris)

Comment: thank you I will study this, I will need some time as I'm not skilled in those matters. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, edit your question to ask for code, since technically requests for services/libraries are not allowed on SO.

Here is the code:

```
function calcSunDate(longitude) {
  let daysSinceEquinox = (Date.now() - new Date("2023-03-20").getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  let daysToLongitude = (longitude / 360) * 365.25;
  let estimatedDate = new Date(Date.now() + daysToLongitude * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  let year = estimatedDate.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
  let month = (estimatedDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let day = estimatedDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let hours = estimatedDate.getHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let minutes = estimatedDate.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");

  return `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}`;
}
```

It calculates the time based on the longitude of these sun.